# How to apply bootgrid filter?

Tags: jquery-bootgrid

I have a bootgrid table with large number of rows.  Is it possible to apply filter on the table?

e.g. each row has an attribute, say type.  I want to display type="A" rows only.

many thx

steve

Comment: can you add some code how you initialize your table and the columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this [solution](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-bootgrid/issues/241):

1. Enable Ajax `ajax : true`.
2. Add this custom search value to your ajax requests like this:

   ```
     $('#grid').bootgrid({ 
     ajax : true,
     url : '/this/is/the/ajax/url',
     otherStuff : ... ,
     requestHandler : function (request) {
         request.searchVal = $('#type').val("A");
         return request;
     }
     });
   ```